# How i loop through my class object add in hashtable object

Tags: c#

```
// this is my class object
Friend f1 = new Friend("Nazir",24);
Friend f2 = new Friend("Hamza", 24);
Friend f3 = new Friend("Abdullah", 23);

Hashtable myhash = new Hashtable();

// add this object in hashtable object
myhash.Add("13b-049-bs",f1);
myhash.Add("13b-034-bs", f1);
myhash.Add("13b-038-bs", f1);

foreach (Friend item in myhash)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key {0}\tName {1}\tAge {2}",item.Name,item.Age,myhash.Keys);
}
```

I got this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in HashTableDemo.exe

Comment: Why are you using the non-typed Hashtable? It would be easier to use a strongly typed `Dictionary<string,Friend>`  - that way you do not have to cast your keys or values. Iterating over it works as well - you'll get stronlgy typed `KeyValuePair<string,Friend>` via `foreach (var kvp in yourDict)` that you then can access by `kvp.Key` and `kvp.Value` without casting...

Answer (score 1):

try out , as data store in hash tbale is not type of `Friend` object youare getting error, if you dont know type than make use of `var` that will resolve error

```
  foreach (var  item in myhash)
        {
           string key = de.Key.ToString();
           Friend val  = (Friend) item.Value;
           Console.WriteLine("Key {0}\tName {1}\tAge {2}", key, val.Name, val.Age );
        }
```

or you can do like this

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry de in myHashtable)
{
      string key = de.Key.ToString();
   Friend val  = (Friend) de.Value;
   Console.WriteLine("Key {0}\tName {1}\tAge {2}", key, val.Name, val.Age );
}
```

Read out : [Hashtable Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Rafalon - why its not good practice ...that is leagal way as per language structure ....it introduced with linq for that purpose only ...any ways i updated my answer with DictionaryEntry  , hope you like to revert you -1 point

Comment: @KonstantinChernov - updated that part also ..............i havent seen that ..thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Rafalon - it debated many time and using or not using it , is on developer , that what my point , in my coding style i use var ..........why not to use lagnaguge is providing that feature ...i am not adding min there

Comment: Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\C sharp\UnderstandingCollection\HashTableDemo\Program.cs 26 35 HashTableDemo

Comment: Please wait for 5 min to edit, I'm trying to edit your question for 5 min now, but you canceled it 4 times `xD` I made some language and code format improvements `:)`

Comment: @SyedNazirHussain - you have to try    string key = de.Key.ToString(); updated same in answer

Comment: @SyedNazirHussain - its working at my end ...please do accept upvote answer if it works at your end tooo

Answer (score 0):

The iterator (enumerator) of `Hashtable` returns objects of type [`DictionaryEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry(v=vs.110).aspx). Therefore, in your `foreach` loop, each item will have two properties: `Key` and `Value`, both of type `object`. You can individually cast the `Key` and `Value` properties on each item to your desired type. For example:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry item in myhash)
{
    // Cast item.Key to string
    string key = (string)item.Key;

    // And cast item.Value to Friend
    Friend friend = (Friend)item.Value;

    Console.WriteLine("Key {0}\tName {1}\tAge {2}", key, friend.Name, friend.Age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use strongly typed Dictionary (`using System.Collections.Generic` needed):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    class Friend
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}    
        public int Age {get;set;}

        public Friend(string name, int age)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // this is my class object
        Friend f1 = new Friend("Nazir", 24);
        Friend f2 = new Friend("Hamza", 24);
        Friend f3 = new Friend("Abdullah", 23);
        var myDict = new Dictionary<string, Friend>();
        // add this object in hashtable object
        myDict["13b-049-bs"] = f1;
        myDict["13b-034-bs"] = f1;
        myDict["13b-038-bs"] = f1;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Friend> item in myDict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key {0}\tName {1}\tAge {2}", item.Key, item.Value.Name, item.Value.Age);
        }
    }
}
```

Strongly typed has the advantage that you never will put an `Enemy` (or some other Type inside this dict - unless it derives from `Friend`.